# Django admin cant display upload files by form

Tags: python, django

I have model where I can upload files without problem, and a model forms which upload the file, which get the path perfectly when I call them in a html loop; but this files can't be accessed by django admin interface. In the two cases the uploaded files can by get in the defined media_root.

What am I doing wrong?

models.py

```
class Documentos(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete="models_CASCADE", null=True, blank=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Arquivo')
    documento = models.FileField(upload_to='')
    data = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    formatado = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Documento'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Documentos'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

forms.py

```
class DocumentosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Documentos
        fields = ['user','nome','documento']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from .forms import *
from .models import *


def alfa(request):
    return render(request, 'pdfupload.html')
# Create your views here.

@login_required(login_url='/register')
def upload(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
        context['url'] = fs.url(name)
    return render(request, 'pdfupload.html', context)

def documentos_lista(request):
    return render(request, 'lista.html')

def upload_documento(request):
    return render(request, 'documento_upload.html')
```

forms.html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="document" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I have my project/urls.py:

```
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am using django 2.1
Even I can't get the uploadedfiles by forms in django admin, no error message is returned.
I am very grateful for your help. Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: Where in your view do you use your `DocumentosForm` to validate and handle the upload? It looks like you do not create a `Documentos` object, save that to the database, etc.

Comment: you are right. It works. I don't believe how I could forget that. Thank you so much.